# bulk update meta value with ajax

Tags: ajax, post-meta

I want to update posts meta value in the wp_query to a different value on click. What I am basically doing is making a notification bubble (like stackoverflow).

1. `wp_query` with the number of posts that have meta value 'unread' - WORKING
2. Show the count bubble on top op logged in user's display name - WORKING
3. On clicking the notification, hide the bubble and change post meta value with ajax only for the posts in the `wp_query` from 'unread' to 'read' so that the count is only visible next when there's a new post with meta value 'unread' - HOW?
4. Show a dropdown of all latest posts with meta value 'read' - maybe another query?

Here's my code for count bubble.

```
add_shortcode('notify', 'notify_member');
    function notify_member() {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $userid = $current_user->ID;
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                'post_type' => 'answer',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'author__not_in' => $userid, //exclude user posts
                'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'question_owner_id'
                        'value' => $userid, //only show posts for the user
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                        array(
                            'key' => '_read_answer'
                            'value' => 'unread', //only show unread posts
                            'compare' => '='
                        ),
                    )
                );
                $questions = new WP_Query( $args );
                $html = '';
                $html .= '<a href="#" class="count">'.$questions->found_posts.'</a>'; //total count
                return $html;
    }
```

I have looked at ajax like and vote tutorials, they tackle one post at a time. I will need the below to work for all returned posts from the query and change at the same time.

```
            if( $questions->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $questions->have_posts() ) { $questions->the_post();
                 update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_read_answer', 'read' ); 
                }
            }
```

I am out of ideas, any direction is welcome. Thanks. P.S. I am not a coder, so please do explain a little.

Comment: If you want to do it with ajax then i have a solution but its not good enough. But if you want i will tell you.

Comment: What do you mean by not good enough? I am open to suggestions. Please do share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After click on `<a>` tage send an ajax request. I will write only php code do `jQuery` part yourself.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        action: 'my_action'
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        //Do watever after you get response
    });
});
</script>
```

In Your `function.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
function my_action(){
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $userid = $current_user->ID; //You can also user get_current_user_id() to get current user id
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'post_type' => 'answer',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'author__not_in' => $userid, //exclude user posts
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'question_owner_id'
                'value' => $userid, //only show posts for the user
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_read_answer'
                'value' => 'unread', //only show unread posts
                'compare' => '='
            ),
         )
    );
    $questions = new WP_Query( $args ); //Get all the post whose meta you want to update
    foreach($questions->posts as $question):
        update_post_meta( $question->ID, '_read_answer', 'read' ); //Update all the posts meta.
    endforeach;
    echo true; //Send the response. You can aslo send response whatever you want.
    die();
}
```

When ever some one click on `a` tag it will send an ajax request to the server. The server run the previous code to get posts whose `meta` you want to update. After getting the post update their `meta` value.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. I will test this and get back to you. Also why is this not good enough?

Comment: Because we will write the whole code again. Their is also another way using `jQuery` but their is also security issue. In this no security issue. :)

Comment: Understood. I will check it tonight and post an update. Thanks

Comment: Thankyou so much, I have a working structure now, with your help and some help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498959/how-to-use-ajax-in-a-wordpress-shortcode/13614297#13614297